# Make nginx detect listening port for call to proxied application

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing

I have an application to which I am proxy_passing request from nginx. Sometimes I wish to restart the application, it takes some time and I wish to have this restart invisible to users. For that I am thinking about running second instance of the application on different port, after it starts I would disable the first instance. After some time I'd like to restart this second instance, so I would start new instance on the first port.

I'd like nginx to detect which proxy port is listening, and use this one. If request starts to fail, I want nginx to start using another port. How do I do that?

I've noticed there is some backup directive for upstream but it seems to assume there is a primary server. I don't want to have primary server - I want to have either this or that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server app1;
        server app2 backup;
     }
}
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

It will always connect to app1 unless it is unavailable. You can update app2 then app1 and the app will always be available.

Comment: According to docs, with such setup if app1 goes down, backup app2 kicks in. But after 10 seconds (default fail_timeout) app1 is considered up again and request are directed again there. They fail and again app2 is being used. Such approach is not really invisible for users because sometimes they will be proxied to the app which is down.

Comment: If app1 is down, requests will be sent to app2, therefore not noticed by the users. If app1 is still down after 10 seconds, app2 will still be used, and users won't get an unavailable.

Comment: Ok. Still I would prefer to make nginx persistently use the last one working application. Anyway, in the config you provided the "backup" doesn't really matter, right?

Comment: It does, otherwise it will do round-robin and connect to app1 and app2. When you upgrade your app, users will get errors

Comment: But the docs says regarding round-robin: "If an error occurs during communication with a server, the request will be passed to the next server,".